# Angular - Wait for function call to finish, to proceed with code

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, frontend

I am writing a piece of code which is checking whether 2 medicines will cause an adverse drug reaction.

My checkForClash() function makes a call to a function getCollisionsList(), which should populate the variable insteractionsLists.

A section of the code is as follows (ignore the usingSynonym bit)

```
 if(usingSynonum){

       interactionsLists = await this.getCollisionsList(i, idOfSyn);


       }else {

       interactionsLists = await this.getCollisionsList(i, listOfAllMeds2[j].id);

       }

       console.log("WHAT IS BEING EXAMINED " + interactionsLists[i].length);
```

The issue here is the 'WHAT IS BEING EXAMINED' i.e interactionsList[i].length is 0, because the call to getCollisionsList, which populated the interactionsLists, has not yet completed.

Here is the getCollisionsLists function:

```
   getCollisionsList(i, id): DrugInteraction[][] {
        let interactions: Array<DrugInteraction> = new Array<DrugInteraction>();
         let dataa = {};
        this.httpClient.getInteractionById(id).subscribe(data => {

            dataa=data;

            const JSONdata: any = data;
            console.log("DATA " + data.length);



            for (let i = 0; i < JSONdata.length; i++) {
                const int: DrugInteraction = new DrugInteraction(JSONdata[i].drug_id, JSONdata[i].name, JSONdata[i].description);
                interactions.push(int);
            }



        });

        interactionsLists.push(interactions);
        return interactionsLists;

    }
```

As you can see by what the console prints out, the function does fetch the 'DATA', but the checkForClash (main) function continues on with the code without waiting for this data to be filled into the interactionsLists.
Here is console output:

```
[Log] WHAT IS BEING EXAMINED 0 
[Log] DATA 645 
[Log] DATA 1706
```

I would like the data to be added before the code continues on... can I make the main function wait for the getCollisionsList function to complete?

Sorry for the mess of the code, I am very new to Angular and I have tried everything to try and make this work.

Comment: `await` used on Promises. You dont return such, so it doesnt wait

Comment: Your best option is really to refactor the service to return the request observable and then use a joining operator (probably `forkJoin` in this use case) to combine the two observables. Then use a `map` operator to evaluate any interactions.

Comment: I don't understand promises very well...could you explain how I could use one here? I don't necessarily need to return data, just get it to wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert Observable to a Promise with `toPromise()` and `await` them inside `async` function (used an IIFE as it seems logical in your context):

```
(async function() {
  if (usingSynonum) {
    await this.getCollisionsList(i, idOfSyn);
  } else {
    await this.getCollisionsList(i, listOfAllMeds2[j].id);
  }
  console.log(...)
})();
```

...

```
getCollisionsList(i, id) {
  let interactions: Array<DrugInteraction> = new Array<DrugInteraction>();
  let dataa = {};
  return this.httpClient.getInteractionById(id).toPromise().then(
    data => {
      ... work with your response
```

And do not subscribe if you return `toPromise()`.

I havent finished the snippet, because you indentations are messed up, but you have all the necessary code here.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I'm trying to adapt the getCollisionsList method and getting the following error
```  error TS2740: Type 'Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'DrugInteraction[][]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```
Have you any idea why it doesn't like this?

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot to remove `DrugInteraction[][]`. Removed the return type. Add it as per your needs